# how to debug web server on RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, thin, webrick

I currently have a problem with a project.

it freezes before it shows the "Started GET ...." seems like it hits an infinite loop.

now i dont really have much experience with debuggers in ROR, can anyone recommend anything i can use to trace the exact origin of the problem. if i can get an error code somewhere then i might be able to fix it.

currently i am using webrick, i tried thin and it gave the exact same error.but i am willing to use anything to find the exact origin of this error.

it seems to be related to the project because all other projects works fine on my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Rails guide on debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html).

Also try running the Rails console ("rails c"); if you can get to a command prompt at all that means that the issue is not in loading the Rails environment (e.g. a problem in application.rb) but is somewhere in the process of making a web request.  If there's a failure it may give you a better error message.

Comment: thanks, but the rails console work perfectly, the functions have no problems. i installed ruby-debug and tried to run it, i dont get any output cause it just keeps hanging. any other suggestions?

Comment: From the rails console, try calling `app.get '/path'` (where "path" is replaced with whatever path you were trying to visit via the web.  That will simulate visiting the page, and may give you a better sense of how far it's getting. You might also try adding some debug statements in the controller to see if it's hitting the controller at all, and how far it's getting.

Comment: thanks jacob, i seem to have found an error code... finally a starting point point. it seems the log4r caught it. rails default logger just froze along.. so i assumed log4r would do the same. once again thanks ALOT